# Despotify segfaults when playing song

Tags: command-line, homebrew, segmentation-fault

On my mac I installed despotify using `brew install -HEAD despotify` when playing a song I get

```
Ouch, I segfaulted. How embarrassing. :-(
Abort trap: 6
```

I have these brew packages installed, I couldn't fing a list of dependancies so this may the the issue:

```
autoconf        gettext         intltool        libidn          mpg123          tokyo-cabinet
automake        glib            libao           libogg          mutt            xz
bitlbee         gmp             libffi          libtasn1        nettle
despotify       gnutls          libgcrypt       libtool         p11-kit
finch           gstreamer       libgpg-error    libvorbis       pkg-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Spotify (the service, not the program) changed their network protocol, and removed support for the old version that Despotify was using.

At the point in time when they did this, all clients based on the despotify library suddenly stopped working. They will not start working again until and unless someone contributes code to despotify that supports the new network protocol.

Source: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=13443